# How to access HP-ALM data through macros?

Tags: vba, alm

I'm working on a utility that can extract the data from ALM server using Excel macros. I am able to connect to the ALM server. 
I need some document/reference where I can learn to use this API.

Any input will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you use the OTA API. Reference can be found in the Help Center of your ALM or online http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/webframe.html.

Comment: Thanks Roland! 
I'll go through that.